# My module does not work and displays an error page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I made a module for Drupal 8.9

https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3076032/-/tree/master

On my `/user/ID/tasks` page I have this error :

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission() must
> implement interface Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface, string
> given, called in
> /var/www/www-example-com/web/modules/custom/task_notify/src/Controller/TaskNotifyUserController.php
> on line 19 in
> Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission() (line 116 of
> core/lib/Drupal/Core/Access/AccessResult.php).

What did I do wrong in my module ?

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\task_notify\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

class TaskNotifyUserController extends ControllerBase {

  public function Tasks() {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'task_notify_user_template',
    ];
  }

  public function taskAccess(AccountInterface $account) {
    return AccessResult::allowedIf($account->id() == $this->currentUser()->id())
      ->orIf(AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission('administer users'));
  }

}
```

Comment: Please paste code into the question. many people will not follow links however OK they may look on the surface

Comment: Rather than pasting a link to your code you should paste your code here - that way it will likely get a better response.

Comment: The first argument needs to be the `$account` object in `AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'administer users')`

Comment: @baikho i don't understand what i should do

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by the documentation, the function

```
Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission(AccountInterface $account, $permission)
```

needs **two** parameters, the first one would be the account on which you need the permission to be, and the second will be the permission you are looking to validate.

> **Parameters**
>
> **[\Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountInterface.php/interface/AccountInterface/8.2.x) $account**: The account for which to check a permission.
>
> **string $permission**: The permission to check for.

<sup>*Source: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Access%21AccessResult.php/function/AccessResult%3A%3AallowedIfHasPermission/8.2.x*</sup>

So your code should be:

```php
public function taskAccess(AccountInterface $account) {
    return AccessResult::allowedIf(
        $account->id() == $this->currentUser()->id()
    )->orIf(
        AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission(
            $account, 'administer users'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: I updated my code but it doesn't work https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/zenimagine-3076032/-/tree/master I got an error `RuntimeException: Callable "Drupal\task_notify\Controller\TaskNotifyUserController::taskAccess" requires a value for the "$user" argument. in Drupal\Component\Utility\ArgumentsResolver->handleUnresolvedArgument() (line 142 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/ArgumentsResolver.php).`

Comment: You forgot to [dependancy inject](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html) it in your route or to pass the right parameter so the [parameter conversion](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#parameter-conversion) work properly.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is my first module. Can you put an answer with the complete file because for me it seems good to me